# Prevent rules conflicts with htaccess' RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to use some `RewriteRule`s to transform :

- http://example.com/blah  =>  `index.php?id=blah`
- http://example.com/someone/blah  =>  `index.php?id=blah&user=someone`

Here is the `htaccess` :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?id=$2&user=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But it seems that the two last rules are incompatible : with this `htaccess`, I get some `500 Internal Server Error`.

**How to create two rules such that they do not "overlap" each other?**

*Notes :*

- *each of these 2 rules work alone*
- *when I use the second rule, then http://example.com/someone/blah  =>  `index.php?id=blah&user=someone` works, but it seems that the root folder is no more `/`  but `/someone/` and then the CSS are not found... How to prevent the base folder to be changed in this case ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 issues:

1. your first rule `(.*)` will convert anything into `/index.php?id=$1`
2. your second rule does not verify if a file or folder exists and might fall into a infinite loop causing a `500 internal server error`.
3. the order of your rules
4. you're using relative paths to serve CSS and Images which causes it to fail with your URL formats, such as `domain.com/anything/anything`

To fix the redirect issue, you can use this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?id=$2&user=$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Since I've changed the regex (to `([^/]+)` which means anything not a `/`) that catches the data you want and the order won't matter in this scenario as it will specifically match:

```
domain.com/anything
```

And

```
domain.com/anything/anything
```

To fix the CSS and Images you can use the `base` TAG to define your absolute URL into your HTML:

```
<base href="http://domain.com/">
```

Comment: More generally (not here specifically), how would you add a fallback? ie `if none of the listed conditions are satisfied, then go to url /`

Comment: @Basj see update... Last rule will catch anything not defined to anywhere else and send it to `/`.

Comment: Thanks @Prix ! Is it possible that in such a case (fallback), the URL displayed in the browser is not `example.com/myuncaughtURL` nor   `example.com/index.php`  but just `example.com/` ?

Comment: @Basj Yes, see update. The last rule means, if URL is not `domain.com/myuncaughturl` or `domain.com/index.php` go to `domain.com/`. **Although you might want to place that last rule at the top depending on what you're actually trying to do there.**

Comment: Oh maybe I explained wrong @Prix : what I want is nothing related to `myuncaughturl` or `index.php`, these were just *examples*  (sorry I explained wrong) ... Basically I just want that if the 2 conditions are not satisfied, then 1) load the page `/index.php`   2) show `example.com/` as browser URL... Could you update for this ? Sorry I was not very clear

Comment: You mean if your current 2 rules are not met? Then you will have to make a redirect using your code, `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');exit;`. As that is beyond what rewrite rules are for specially since those 2 formats of URL's are handled by your index.php file.

Comment: Yes @Prix, if the 2 rules are not met, exactly. Can I do this redirect in htaccess instead of PHP `header("Location: /");` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62701/discussion-between-basj-and-prix).

Comment: **No, you cannot because you're redirecting `anything` and `anything/anything` and not predefined URLs to your file which is where it should be handled.** More specifically speaking, the `mod_rewrite` does not know a URL failed when you're telling it to redirect `anything` as they are all sent to your code which is what should handle it in this case.